# Mongoose Schema Types Throwing Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out why my schema array reference is throwing an error for the array line `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`. I am trying to reference my second collection model with this array, but I'm getting `Cannot read property Types of undefined`

Here is my error:

```
imagesModel.js:10
    description_id: { type: mongoose.Scehma.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Description'}
                                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Types' of undefined
```

Here is the model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var descriptionSchema = new Schema({
    pattern: String,
    color: String,
    body: String,
    images: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Images'}]
});

var Description = mongoose.model('Description', descriptionSchema);

module.exports = Description;
```

Here is the Images model that is the reference:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imageSchema = new Schema({
    pattern: String,
    color: String,
    imageName: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    imageSource: String,
    description_id: { type: mongoose.Scehma.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Description'}
});

imageSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var Description = require("../models/descriptionModel");
    var image = this;
    Description.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: {$in: {image.description_id}},
        {$push: {images: image._id}},
        next
    });
});

var Images = mongoose.model('Images', imageSchema);

module.exports = Images;
```

Comment: Typo. `Scehma`. See it now?

Comment: It's just a typo: change `Scehma` to `Schema`.